# With webpack, babel-preset-env for node transpiles es6 modules to es5

Tags: webpack, es6-modules

When i use webpack with babel-preset-env configured for node with this configuration:

```
{
    target: 'node',
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
      server: ['./src/server.js'],
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].bundle.js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].bundle.js',
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['env', {
                targets: {
                  node: "current",
                },
              }],
              'react'
            ],
          },
        },
      }],
    },
}
```

My server use some es modules which are well detect by webpack like:

```
[319] ./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/withRouter.js 395 bytes {0} [built]
```

My problem is that **es modules** are transpiled into **es5 one** in the bundle, what i do wrong ?

Webpack 3.6
babel-preset-node 1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm sorry, es modules are not written in es6 but es5 with require replaced by import. So in order to use es6 code from node_modules/ looks like we have to use their src/ folder instead.

Comment: Can you post your config using Webpack, babel-preset-env, react with ES6?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `libraryTarget` to your config:

```
output: {
  filename: ...,
  pathL ...,
  libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
},
```

And es modules isn't supported in node right now (only supported if you run with flag) so I think webpack's output is fine.

Comment: i expect babel to keep const, arrow functions and so on from these dependencies instead of transpiling all the thing in cjs

Comment: Because you use `node: "current",` what version of node do you use now?

Comment: Node 7.8 but i get the same problem with last browser config.